# Bash to SSH copy Linux command output to remote Windows Host

Tags: windows, bash, ssh

I need to take the output of some Linux commands and files (containing letters, numbers, symbols, white space and newlines), stored in a local Bash variable (dynamically generated) and then send the contents of the variable to a remote Windows host using SSH, appending to a specified file.

I've attempted many variations of the following command without any success:

`echo "ECHO $result >> $out_file" | ssh $remote_host`

The special characters (<, > etc.) and newlines that exist in the input make it a mess, meaning the input is interpreted as many commands rather than a single chunk of input.

It is infeasible for me to change the format input itself, do I need to do some escaping?

Any tips on how I can achieve the desired result?

Edit: the commands themselves are hard coded, as are their arguments. The output of each command is concatenated to a variable, $result, and then the intention is to send the content of that variable via SSH and append it to the remote file.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to quote `"$remote_host"`, but see [**BASH/FAQ 50**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (P.S.... How's McBarker?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for suggestion and the site. I've updated the answer with an edit to better clarify my situation. (He's still as cute(?) as ever!)

Comment: Where the confusion comes from is `echo "ECHO $result >> $out_file"` will output a literal `ECHO $result >> $out_file"` on `stdout` which you *pipe* to `stdin` for `ssh $remote_host`.  `ssh $remote_host` will start a remote process on `$remote_host` which has no concept of what `stdin` is on the original host. If you want provide `$result` to the foreign host as part of the `ssh` command, it has to be part of the command, e.g. `ssh $remote_host "command"` where `command` is what will be executed on the remote host (e.g. `ssh $remote_host 'tail -n 10 /home/$USER/.bashrc'`

Comment: It appears that piping to `ssh` (as I have done) causes it to enter it on the Windows terminal, whereas providing it as an argument to `ssh` (as you are suggesting) causes it to be executed on a shell on the Windows machine, is this a correct synopsis?

Comment: Yes, with the qualifier, that the windows host never sees `stdin` from the linux box. Let's say I have a host `alchw` and I want to send the variable `v` containing `v=cat` to `alchw`, then, e.g. `v=cat; ssh alchw "echo $v; sleep 10"` will execute `echo cat` on `alchw` sleep on `alchw` for 10 seconds and return. However, if I try and *pipe* `cat` to the ssh process it is never seen, because the ssh process is running on a foreign host, e.g. `echo cat | ssh alchw "read -t 5 v; echo $v"` never reads anything.

Comment: To avoid confusion with the `cat` command, change `cat` to `dog` above. It is just the contents of the variable and not a second command.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. The issue now becomes getting sanitising newlines etc. For example, `v=$vmstat; ssh alchw "echo $v >> file.txt" `

Comment: **`v=$(vmstat); ssh alchw "echo $v >> file.txt" `

Comment: Why not sharing the folder with the output file on the windows machine. Mount it on your linux machine via smb and write the output directly to your file via `echo "${result}" >> /mount/winmachine/${out_file}`?

Comment: Customer wishes override simple solutions like this.